AutoItalicWords Option not working
If I evaluate the following code
CreateDocument[
 TextCell["cherry toast banana", "Text", 
  AutoItalicWords -> {"cherry"},
  FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]]

I get

Note that "cherry" is not italicized. Can someone confirm whether or not this is a bug?

Version Number: 14.1.0.0
Platform : Mac OS X ARM (64-bit)
MacOS Sonoma Version 14.5


There is nothing "potential" about it.  It's a bug. :)

Has this bug been reported to Wolfram?

I get the same result as you in Version 14.0.0
